# WCF POST parameter and non-JSON body (base64)

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I want to not put JSON data in the body AND use a parameter in the URI

I am able to get JSON data through by using something like this.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "Checkin/SetPicture/{PatientProfileId}",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, // this is key for combining params with Stream
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Stream SetPicture(string PatientProfileId, PictureData data);
```

and PictureData - very simple:

```
[DataContract]
class PictureData {
    [DataMember]
    internal string Base64 { get; set; }
}
```

If I post something like this it works (from the REST console/client)

```
    http://localhost:9001/Checkin/SetPicture/666
    Content-Type:  application/json
    Body - 
{ "Base64": "AAAAAA" }
```

If I want just the Base64 string in the body, and not JSON, how do I do it?  Right now it gives a response back of "Server Error - check logs", but of course there is nothing in the log.  It's a parsing issue from the contract since the class is never hit.

```
ie Body - 

AAAAAA
```

Here is a related SO query but doesn't quite get me what I need.

[Passing XML string in the body of WCF REST service using WebInvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253163/passing-xml-string-in-the-body-of-wcf-rest-service-using-webinvoke)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137314/how-to-accept-parameters-including-images-through-a-json-web-service-and-store/28137858#28137858

Comment: Thanks, i tried it but still has the same generic 'server error'.  I would think that approach would work, not sure what I am missing.